# Buscar posiciones en un texto

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Situación

Tengo una aplicación Rails usando Postgresql.

Se agregan textos a la aplicación (que varían en tamaño, desde unas pocas palabras hasta, digamos, 5,000 palabras).

El texto se analiza/parsea, primero automáticamente y luego a mano, para asociar cada palabra / posición en el texto con información específica (parte de oración -- verbo/sustantivo/etc. -- etiquetas gramaticales, lema (palabra base -- voy ==> ir), definition_id, etc.).

Dado un lema (palabra base), o una parte de oración (verbo/sustantivo), o etiquetas gramaticales, o un definition_id (o una combinación), necesito poder encontrar todas las otras posiciones de texto en la base de datos que contienen la misma información (lema / parte de oración / id_definición / etc.).

### Conflicto

No puedo hacer una búsqueda de texto completo porque, por ejemplo, si hago clic en "left" en "I left Nashville" (me fui de Nashville), no quiero que aparezca "turn left at the light" (gira a la izquierda en el semáforo). Solo quiero "Leave" (irse) como verbo, así como otras formas de "Leave" como verbo.

Además, podría querer solo "izquierda" con un definition_id específico (ej. "Izquierda" usado como "El partido político", no usado como "lo contrario de la derecha").

En resumidas cuentas, estoy buscando algunos consejos sobre cuál de las 3 rutas debo seguir (las que explico a continuación).

### Soluciones

Hay tres opciones en las que puedo pensar:

**1: TextPosition**
Una tabla TextPosition para almacenar cada posición de palabra, con columnas para cada uno de los atributos anteriores.

Esto haría que la búsqueda fuera muy fácil, pero habría MUCHOS registros (1 para cada posición), pero ¿tal vez eso no sea un problema? ¿Almacenar esta cantidad de entradas es una mala idea por alguna razón específica?

**2: JSON en el objeto de Texto**
Una columna JSON en el objeto Text, para almacenar todas las posiciones de palabras en un gran arreglo de hashes, o un hash de hashes (con cada clave del hash externo representando una posición de texto, cada valor un hash con la información de esa posición).

Esto agregaría cero registros, pero, a) Construir una consulta para buscar todos los textos con cierta información probablemente sería difícil, b) Esa búsqueda probablemente sería lenta, y c) Podría ocupar más espacio de almacenamiento que una tabla separada.

**3: DOS columnas JSON: uno en Text, otro en cada registro del diccionario**

1. Un JSON en cada objeto de texto, como en la opción 2, pero solo para renderizar el texto (no para buscar), que contiene toda la información sobre cada posición en ese mismo texto.
2. Otro JSON en cada "objeto de diccionario" (definición, palabra base, concepto gramatical, etiqueta gramatical), solo para poder buscar (no para renderizar). Esta columna rastrearía las coincidencias de este objeto en TODOS los textos. Sería un arreglo de hashes, donde cada hash sería { text_id: x, text_index: y }.

Con esta opción, la búsqueda sería "más fácil", pero aún así no sería idónea: para encontrar todas las posiciones de texto que contienen un atributo determinado, tendría que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Encontrar el registro de ese atributo
2. Extraer los text_ids / indices del registro
3. Buscar los textos con esos IDs
4. Extraer la línea coincidente de cada texto, usando el índice que viene con cada text_id dentro del JSON.

Si se tratara de una combinación de atributos, tendría que hacer esos 4 pasos por cada atributo, y luego encontrar la intersección entre los conjuntos de coincidencias de cada atributo (para al final solo tener las posiciones que contengan ambos).

Cuando se actualiza una posición (por ejemplo, si un usuario indica que un atributo está mal, y que debe ser otro), tendría que actualizar ambos JSONs.

Además, ¿almacenar 2 columnas de JSON realmente aportará algún beneficio sobre una tabla TextPosition? Probablemente ocuparía MÁS espacio de almacenamiento que el uso de una tabla TextPosition, y ¿para qué ventaja?

### Conclusión

En resumen, estoy buscando algunos consejos sobre cuál de esas 3 rutas debería seguir.

Espero que la respuesta sea "opción 1", pero si es así, me encantaría saber qué inconvenientes / obstáculos podrían surgir más tarde cuando haya muchísimos registros.

Comment: Hola has leído en la documentación de PostgreSQL el mudulo de FTS tal vez te de algunas ideas al respecto pues puede que haya algo que puedas reutilizar de ahí https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

Comment: Sí, lo he leído, el problema es que necesito buscar no solo por texto sino por objetos relacionados (como un definition_id, etiquetas gramaticales, etc.)

Comment: Pero hoy aprendí de alguien más experimentado que puede soportar millones de registros fácilmente, que “Postgres es una gran bestia”. Así que pienso simplemente guardar cada posición en su propio registro, valdrá la pena.